# When adding Xaml code to project the wpf window won't load

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a WPF application with Helix Toolkit that currently loads a 3D model to show on the window.

From the moment when i add  to the xaml file it won't start up anymore and it doesn't give an error..

```
<Window x:Class="fyssim.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:fyssim"
    xmlns:h="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
    xmlns:HelixToolkit="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
```

XAML CODE WITHOUT THE GRID

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Create3DViewPort();
        device3D.Content = Display3d(MODEL_PATH);
        // Add to view port
        ViewPort.Children.Add(device3D);

        RotateModel();
    }

    private void Create3DViewPort()
    {
        var lights = new DefaultLights();
        var teaPot = new Teapot();
        ViewPort.Children.Add(lights);
        this.AddChild(ViewPort);
        ViewPort.LookAt(new Point3D(0, 0, 2));
    }

    private Model3D Display3d(string model)
    {
        Model3DGroup device = null;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!!!");
            ViewPort.RotateGesture = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick);
            ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();
            device = import.Load(model);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Error : " + e.StackTrace);
        }
        return device;
    }

    private void RotateModel()
    {
        var axis = new Vector3D(1, 0, 0);
        var angle = 90;

        var matrix = device3D.Transform.Value;
        matrix.Rotate(new Quaternion(axis, angle));

        device3D.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(matrix);
    }
```

c# code that imports the model

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You mean you were not able to see the window in designer mode or window at run time? Sometimes Visual Studio does not shows up some windows at designer time due to some wrong or improper namespaces found in xaml. I guess this could be same in your case.

Comment: The code as it is works, when i add the <Grid></Grid> it doesn't work anymore which is weird because it is generated code from Visual Studio itself. When i remove the <Grid></Grid> block it works again..